# Java outputstream into a workbook

Tags: java, excel, upload, apache-poi, vaadin

I upload my excel files using Vaadin framework's file uplaod tool, which returns me an outputstream. I want to read cells of that excel file probably using apache poi.

But I couldn't figure out how can I turn that outputstream into a workbook or anything useful that I can use with POI?

Comment: I don't do Vaadin, but are you sure that you're using it the right way? The upload tool returning an `OutputStream` seems fairly useless. To get the right answer you probably want to reframe your question into something like "How to get an `InputStream` of the uploaded file in Vaadin?". The Excel/POI part is totally irrelevant here. You already know that they actually need an `InputStream` anyway.

Comment: +1 I maybe wrong with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why to worry about that outputstream...if you have that file in you server use poi to do the work...if only outputstream is availble write it into a file and then use poi.

Comment: what do you mean? file needs to be uploaded by user first. I dont wanna bother finding and reading the right directory from tomcat, check if that file is correct..etc. Just wanna read the moment i receive it from strean

Comment: Poi will take only inputstream..so you will have to convert that output to input or into a file

Comment: @Jasmin I prefer to read what i just receive rather than figure and find out where it is uploaded in tomcat

Comment: @Spring So Only option is to convert it into an inputstream..
This might help you..

http://ostermiller.org/convert_java_outputstream_inputstream.html

Comment: indeed I can create a File and then read it, streaming is not necessary tnx